# Adding the results of a column to another column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to show the contents of two tables; my query is this:

```
SELECT ID, 
    post_author, 
    post_content, 
    post_title, 
    post_name, 
    guid, 
    post_type, 
    meta_id, 
    post_id, 
    meta_key, 
    meta_value 
FROM wp_posts, 
    wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id 
    AND post_author IN (2);
```

The meta_key column stores the TYPE of content I need like website, latitude, longitude, phone, email. Is there a way to make this column explode to another columns? For example:

```
ID, 
post_author, 
..., 
meta_id, 
post_id, 
meta_key, 
meta_value, 
website(its a meta_key result), 
latitude(another meta_key result), 
longitude(anoter meta_key result)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what are you trying to do, but I think you need to display the meta key and values as columns' headers with the meta values as the values for each column. In this case you can do something like this:

```
SELECT  
  ID, 
  post_author, 
  post_content,   
  post_title, 
  post_name, 
  guid, 
  post_type, 
  meta_id, 
  post_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'website'   THEN meta_value END) AS website,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'latitude'  THEN meta_value END) AS latitude,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'longitude' THEN meta_value END) AS longitude,
  ...
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_author IN (2)
GROUP BY Id, post_author, ...
```

**Things to note:**

- Try to avoid the old `JOIN` syntax that you used in your query; [*it is a bad habit*](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) , and use the ANSI-SQL-92 syntax using the `JOIN` key word instead like what I did.
- I used the `MAX` as a work around to pivot the rows into columns, you will need to list the columns that are not in the aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Look at this screenshot, there you can see the geo_latitude and geo_longitude as a meta_key result, i whant to make it show in another column... its that possible?

http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/4562/query.jpg

Comment: @JefersonSantos - Yes, that is what my query do. Have you tried it?

Comment: ohh i forgot to tell, on meta_value there are values related to meta_key, so i whant to make a geo_latitude column with the data from the meta_value line on the screenshot but with separated columns, like: 

    | ID | post_author | ... | geo_latitude | geo_longitude |... 
    |5281|     3       | ... | -56.0....... | 15.62........ |...


the query on the screen is my first post query.

   SELECT ID, post_author, post_content, post_title, post_name, guid, post_type, meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND post_author IN (3)

Comment: oh i am sorry i dont know how to make a code tag in this comment box

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!! i have understanded your comment, it works like a charm.
'code'SELECT 
 ID,
 post_author,
 post_content, 
 post_title, post_name, 
 guid, 
 post_type, 
 meta_id, 
 post_id, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'address'  THEN meta_value END) AS address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'website'  THEN meta_value END) AS website
 FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_author IN (2) AND post_type = 'place'
GROUP BY ID, 
  post_author, 
  post_content,   
  post_title, 
  post_name, 
  guid, 
  post_type, 
  meta_id, 
  post_id 'code'